# Confused about Tensor Product of R-modules

Tags: modules, tensor-products, free-modules

In Tu's book on Differential Geometry he first defines $Free(V\times W)$ as:

$$\sum r_i(v_i, w_i), r_i \in R, (v_i, w_i) \in V \times W$$
where the sum is finite.

The way I understand it is the above construction is of formal combinations and forgets the actual structure of the modules. In other words, if $v_1+v_2 = v_3$, it isn't true that in $Free(V\times W)$ that $(v_1, 0) + (v_2, 0) = (v_3, 0)$

Now to form the tensor product we quotient by the submodule, $S$ spanned by elements of the form:
$$ (v_1 + v_2, w) - (v_1, w) - (v_2, w)\\
 (v,w_1 + w_2) - (v, w_1) - (v, w_2)\\
 (rv,w) - r(v,w)\\
 (v, rw) - r(v,w)$$
Then we have a map from the product to the tensor product,
$$(v,w) \rightarrow v\otimes w$$

However, if $v_3 = v_1 + v_2$, then I can't show that $$v_3\otimes w = v_1 \otimes w + v_2 \otimes w$$
which should be the case if $\otimes$ is a <strike>module homomorphism</strike> bilinear map.

Comment: The mapping $\otimes$ is *not* a module homomorphism: it is $\mathbf RR$-bilinear but not $\mathbf R$-linear.  There is a difference between bilinear mappings and linear mappings (think about the dot product). Part of the point of the tensor product is to "reduce" questions about bilinear mappings out of $V \times W$ to linear mappings out of $V \otimes_\mathbf R W$.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected that part. However, I still don't see how to show what I need to show which should be true given the bilinearity of the map.

Comment: That relation is literally one of the relations in the submodule $S$: modulo $S$, you are forcing $(v_1+v_2,w) - (v_1,w) - (v_2,w)$ to be $0$, which is saying $(v_1+v_2,w) = (v_1,w) + (v_2,w)$ in ${\rm Free}(V \times W)/S$, and that's the same thing as $(v_1+v_2)\otimes w = v_1\otimes w + v_2 \otimes w$ by the definition of the notation $v \otimes w$.

Comment: The notation $v_1+v_2$ is not some abstract formal sum: it is literally adding in $V$.  The free vector space with basis $V \times W$ involves formal sums of pairs in $V \times W$, not formal sums in $V$ and formal sums in $W$.  Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506381/help-me-understand-the-tensor-product will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, @KCd. That was my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $V \otimes W := \operatorname{Free}(V \times W)/S$ and $\otimes : V \times W \to V \otimes W$ is defined by $$(v,w) \mapsto v \otimes w := (v,w)+S,$$ the condition $(v_1 + v_2, w) - ((v_1, w) + (v_2, w)) \in S$ tells us that $$(v_1 + v_2, w)+S = ((v_1, w) + (v_2, w))+S = ((v_1,w)+S) + ((v_2,w)+S)$$
which is the same as $(v_1 + v_2) \otimes w = v_1 \otimes w + v_2 \otimes w$. Also observe that the other relations which define $S$ gives us \begin{align} v \otimes (w_1+w_2) &= v \otimes w_1 + v \otimes w_2, \\ (rv) \otimes w &= r(v \otimes w), \\ v \otimes (rw) &= r(v \otimes w).\end{align}

---

Recall that if $M$ is an $R$-module and $S$ is a submodule of $M$, the quotient $M/S$ is defined by $M/\!\sim$, where $$(\forall u_1,u_2 \in U) \quad u_1 \sim u_2 \iff u_1-u_2 \in S.$$ In this case, the equivalence class of $m \in M$ is given by $m+S := \{m+s : s \in S\}$ (hence $m+S = m'+S \iff m-m' \in S$), and we define an $R$-module structure in $M/S$ by $$(\forall m,m' \in M)(\forall r \in R) \quad r(m+S)+(m'+S) := (rm+m')+S.$$

Comment: Maybe, I am missing something, but I don't know how this shows that $v_3\otimes w = v_1 \otimes w + v_2 \otimes w$. Haven't you only shown that $(v_1+v_2)\otimes w = v_1 \otimes w + v_2 \otimes w$

Comment: I don't see any difference between $(v_1+v_2)\otimes w = v_1 \otimes w + v_2 \otimes w$ and $v_3 \otimes w = v_1 \otimes w + v_2 \otimes w$ for $v_3 = v_1+v_2$ :/

Comment: I guess you are right, now that I think about it. I was a bit confused on the elements of the $Free(V \times W)$. It seems that $(v_1 + v_2, w)$ isn't an actual element in it when I look at the definition. So the quotient relations would actually include something like $v_3\otimes w - v_1 \otimes w - v_2 \otimes w$. For some reason, I was thinking that $(v_1 + v_2, w)$ was still a formal linear combination so that we could not assert that it was equal to $(v_3, w)$

Comment: Maybe you miswrote in your last comment: $(v_1+v_2,w)$ *is* an actual element in it, since ${\rm Free}(V \times W)$ is the formal span of all pairs $(v,w)$, so as a special case it really does include $(v,w)$ where $v = v_1+v_2$.

Comment: Actually, $(v_1+v_2,w)$ is an element of $\operatorname{Free}(V \times W)$, and it's different from $(v_1,w)+(v_2,w)$. In general, if $A$ is *any* nonempty set, $\operatorname{Free}(A)$ is an $R$-module containing $A$ as a basis. For that reason, elements of $\operatorname{Free}(A)$ are $R$-linear combinations of elements in $A$. So, $(v_1+v_2,w)$ is a basis element of $\operatorname{Free}(V \times W)$ and not $(v_1,w)+(v_2,w)$, since the latter is a linear combination of $(v_1,w)$ and $(v_2,w)$.

Comment: @KCd What I'm trying to say is that if $v_1 + v_2 = v_3$, then $(v_3, w)$ and $(v_1, w)$ and $(v_2, w)$ are in $Free(V \times W)$. As a formal symbol $(v_1 + v_2, w)$ is not in the set. Only if you first replace it with its sum from the underlying module. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Jeff But $(v_1 + v_2, w) \in V \times W \subseteq \operatorname{Free}(V \times W)$.

Comment: @azif00 Are you suggesting that both if $v_1 + v_2 = v_3$, then both $(v_3, w)$ and $(v_1 + v_2, w)$ are in $Free(V\times W)$. That doesn't make sense to me, since they are different representations of the same element. The way I understand the construction, is that you have to evaluate the $+$ first to get a set of symbols to construct it and while that there is something in it equivalent to $(v1+v2, w)$, the symbol with $(v1+v2, w)$ is not in it.

Comment: If $v = v'$ in $V$, then $(v,w)$ and $(v',w)$ are literally the *same thing*.  In $\mathbf R^2$, $(1+5,7)$ and $(6,7)$ are the same thing.  The addition in the notation $(v_1+v_2,w)$ is *not* a formal thing, as I said elsewhere here. Therefore if $v_3 = v_1 + v_2$ *in* $V$ (not a formal sum, but actual addition in $V$), then $(v_3,w)$ and $(v_1+v_2,w)$ are literally the *same thing*. Math doesn't know about notation ("you wrote something in $V$ as a sum in $V$, so now it no longer means the same thing" -- incorrect!).

Comment: @KCd I guess we are getting down to some subtle semantics at this point. My mental model of a free module is that you take some discrete set of symbols and form formal linear combinations of them. In your example on $R^2$, I would claim that, as a formal symbol, $6$ is in $R$ but there is no symbol $5 + 1$ as that is a function of two elements of $R$. Maybe, this is the wrong way to thin about it and I get that there is something equivalent to it in the free module, so at this point, I think we are mainly arguing about notation.

Comment: You do not understand  the way a free vector space on a set works when the set is a vector space (overloaded notation).Write each $v$ in $\mathbf R^2$ as $\delta_v$ or $[v]$ when viewing it in the free vector space on $\mathbf R^2$ in order to make it less easy to get confused about what + really means. In the free vector space on $\mathbf R^2$, $\delta_{(4+2,3)} + 7\delta_{1,9}$, the $+$ in $4+2$ is ordinary addition while the + between the deltas is not: $\delta_{(4+2,3)} + 7\delta_{(1,9)}$ is absolutely the same thing as $\delta_{(6,3)} + 7\delta_{(1,9)}$ and you can't simplify it any more.

Comment: @KCd Yes, I got that point already, that we aren't taking formal linear combinations of symbols when looking at the $+$ inside your $\delta_{(4+2, 3)}$ example. As you say, $4+2$ and $6$ are the same thing.

Comment: @KCd For me personally and maybe others new to the concept, since a free vector space is a formal linear combination of an abstract set of symbols, it is slightly simpler to describe it as formal linear combinations of "reduced" symbols, i.e. when we write a formal linear combination of $(v,w)$ where $v=6$, we would write it as $(6,w)$ instead of $(4+2,w)$ because there is some ambiguity as to whether they are different elements of the Free Vector space. One has to clarify as you have done that $4+2$ is not a formal combination inside of the parentheses.

Comment: Who is to say that an expression is "reduced" and why is 6 "reduced"? A vector space doesn't know if its elements are written in a particular way (no canonical basis). A way to think about a free $\mathbf R$-vector space on a set $X$ that cuts down on confusions if $X$ has more structure than just a set is to think about ${\rm Free}(X)$ as the set of all *functions* $f \colon X \to \mathbf R$ with finite support. Each $x \in X$ leads to a function $\delta_x$ that's 1 at $x$ and 0 elsewhere. Then $f = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i\delta_{x_i}$ where the support is in $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and $c_i = f(x_i)$.

Comment: Ultimately the right viewpoint is to think about free vector spaces by their universal mapping property, but if you're trying to grok the universal mapping property of tensor products then maybe you don't to pile on more than one universal mapping property at a time.  When you do get the point of universal mapping properties they you *will* want to think of as much as you can in those terms.  It gets past all idiosyncracies of defining things as "expressions subject to formal rules" by focusing on the underlying mathematical feature that gets used by the object whenever it is used.

Answer (score 0):

So for posterity, I want to write up an answer for others who may have the same confusion. As @KCd clarified, elements of $Free(V\times W)$ are of the form,

$$\sum r_i(v_i, w_i)$$

However if we write a particular element of $Free(V\times W)$ as $r_1(v_1 + v_2, w_1)$ and $v_3 = v_1 + v_2$ then
$$r_1(v_1 + v_2, w_1) = r_1(v_3, w_1)$$
In other words, inside of our parentheses in our notation we are not taking formal sums, but instead combining elements of the module as we normally would.